# I've switched to nvim and init.lua, which pulls in onedark colorscheme. How can I add a custom rule?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

I have C-style comments inside PHP strings that contain SQL code, so I can easily understand what the query is doing when I see it running on the server.

```
DB::runQuery('/* this is my SUPER complicated update example */

    UPDATE table1 SET foo = "bar"
');
```

How could I add a rule to style that comment-in-a-string differently to the rest of the string?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the syntax file already matches the `/**/` comment in the string, you only need to add a highlight for it.

1. Check the syntax group (*e.g.*, using `zS` from [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) or `synstax#UnderCursor()` from [synstax](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax)).
2. Add highlighting in `~/.vim/after/syntax/php.vim` (or your Vim directory equivalent):

   ```
   highlight [opts] GROUP [stuff] " see :help :highlight
   ```

---

If the syntax file *doesn't* already match the comment in the string… you could try to hack one in (place a `:syntax` command in `~/.vim/after/syntax/php.vim` or equivalent). You could also try a solution using `:help textprop` or `:help matchadd()`.

Comment: I managed to get it working with

autocmd ColorScheme * highlight CommentInString guifg=#fcffc7 guibg=#282c34
autocmd ColorScheme * match CommentInString /'\/\*.\+\*\//

Comment: Any idea how I could highlight the words inside the comment different to the `/* ` and ` */`... I tried messing around with regions and couldn't get anything to work.  I'd quite like to have the words underlined, but not the comment tags, or any leading/trailing whitespace

Comment: @Codemonkey I’m not really an expert in :syntax. Maybe a new question?